# Laravel Expo Push Notification - Not receiving Notification on Android

Tags: laravel, notifications, expo

I am quite new to Laravel and couldn't find any practical example of the library https://github.com/Alymosul/laravel-exponent-push-notifications.
I want to create a simple Welcome-Notification.

My Notification looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use NotificationChannels\ExpoPushNotifications\ExpoChannel;
use NotificationChannels\ExpoPushNotifications\ExpoMessage;

class WelcomeNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct(){
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [ExpoChannel::class];
    }

    public function toExpoPush($notifiable)
    {
        return ExpoMessage::create()
            ->badge(1)
            ->title("Hello World!")
            ->enableSound()
            ->body("Hello World!");
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
        ];
    }
}
```

I already subscribed a user with the help of the subscribe route (successfully created an DB entry).

Now i want to send the notification to the user:

```
public function sendNotification(Request $request)
{
        $getUserByEmail = User::where('email', 'user@email.com')->first();
        $getUserByEmail->notify(new WelcomeNotification());
}
```

I didn't receive the notification. When using the expo notification tool it works as expected.

Could you please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you get Push token after migration and use it when send a notification to a specific device? I can't figure out how to do so and the code provided doesn't include any reference to any keys ... thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem is, that the library laravel-exponent-push-notifications is sending all notifications without a message-channel to the channel 'Default'.

So it would work if i create the **message-channel 'Default'** on the **device**.

Alternatively there are two more options:

**Option 1:**
Create a message channel on the device.

```
import { Notifications } from 'expo';

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        await Notifications.createChannelAndroidAsync('chat-messages', {
            name: 'Chat messages',
            sound: true,
        });
    }
```

2. Send the notification

```
$getUserByEmail = User::where('email', 'user@email.com')->first();
$getUserByEmail->notify(new WelcomeNotification());
```

3. The notification should contain the message channel, registered on the device:

```
public function toExpoPush($notifiable){
        return ExpoMessage::create()
            ->badge(1)
            ->title("Hello World!")
            ->enableSound()
            ->body("Hello World!")
            ->setChannelId("chat-messages");
}
```

**Option 2:**
Change the *toArray()-method* in the file `NotificationChannels\ExpoPushNotifications\
ExpoMessage.php` to something like this:

```
    public function toArray()
    {

        $returnArray = [
            'title'     =>  $this->title,
            'body'      =>  $this->body,
            'sound'     =>  $this->sound,
            'badge'     =>  $this->badge,
            'ttl'       =>  $this->ttl,
            'channelId' => $this->channelId,
            'data'      => $this->jsonData,
        ];

        if (strtolower($this->channelId) == 'default' || $this->channelId == '') {
            unset($returnArray['channelId']);
        }

        return $returnArray;
    }
```

When sending notifications to the **expo** application without a channel, expo is **automatically creating a channel** and you will receive the notification.

#### UPDATE

Also don't forget to register the user in Laravel to be able to receive push-notifications. You can either do that in a custom method or the provided one.

The route can be found (and also changed) in the following file:
`vendor\alymosul\laravel-exponent-push-notifications\src\Http\routes.php`.

Comment: hi can you help me details, I have done the first option still now I am not receive any notification

Comment: How did you intend to use Expo push token in above code to send notifications to a specific device?